# 2 buttons, How to randomly assign one to be true and one to be false in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, random, boolean

I have two buttons, I need to randomly assign random boolean values to each, one to be true and one to be false. For example, clicking one of the buttons should display an alert saying something like "you pressed the true button" if true button is pressed. Any ideas?

Comment: What does it mean to assign one button to be true..? You mean to be hidden or not? To be selectable or not..?

Comment: No the Idea is that they would both be visible, the user has an option to press just one, after pressing one button the user is notified if the button he/she selected was the true or false button, notification disappears and the process begins again with buttons being reassigned random true and false values.

Comment: A button is a button. What you do when the button is tapped is what matters.

Answer (score 1):

In the your view controller class declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *trueButton;
```

In `viewDidLoad` or similar:

```
self.trueButton = arc4random() % 2 ? self.button1 : self.button2;
```

This assumes that you have properties named `button1` and `button2` for the buttons. Change this as necessary to match the actual button variables.

Then, in the button tap event:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:self.trueButton]) [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWith...] show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = arc4random() % 2;
if(i==0)
{
    firstButton.tag = 0;
    secondButton.tag = 1;
}
else
{
    firstButton.tag = 1;
    secondButton.tag = 0;
}
```

then when clicking the button check the tag if it is 1 it is the true button and 0 the false button